# Kendo UI dropdownlist whith server filtering and MVVM Binding

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a kendogrid that I want to edit with an external form. On the external form I have a dropdownlist which is bound to a OData service with serverfiltering=true, The problem is that the dropdownlist does not show the selected item value from the grid model. Here is my script:

```
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="contract_title">Contract Title:</label>
            </div>

            <input id="contract_title" class="k-input" data-type="string" data-bind="value: selected.Title" />

        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="contract_ContractNumber">Contract Number:</label>
            </div>
            <input id="contract_ContractNumber" class="k-input" data-type="string" data-bind="value: selected.ContractNumber" />
        </li>


        <li>

            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="contract_ContractDate">Contract Date:</label>
            </div>
            <input id="contract_ContractDate" data-format="yyyy/MM/dd" data-bind="value: selected.ContractDate" data-role="datepicker" data-parse-formats="yyyy-MM-dd" />

        </li>


        <li>
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="contract_ContractAmount">Contract Amount:</label>
            </div>
            <input id="contract_ContractAmount" class="k-input" data-type="number" data-role="numerictextbox" data-decimals="0" data-format="n0" data-bind="value: selected.ContractAmount" />
        </li>


        <li>
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="contract_SubContractor">Sub Contractor:</label>
            </div>
            <input id="contract_SubContractor" class="k-input" data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="ID" data-value-primitive="true" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value: selected.SubContractorID, source: Companies" />
        </li>


    </ul>

</div>


<div id="contractGrid">
</div>


<script>
    projectid = 34;
    var viewModel = null;
    jQuery(function () {



        viewModel = kendo.observable({
            dataSource: getContractDatasource(),

            selected: {},
            hasChanges: false,
            sync: function () {

            },
            cancel: function () {
                this.dataSource.cancelChanges();

            }
            ,
            Compainies: getContract_SubcontractorsDatasource()
        });


        kendo.bind($("#aeContract"), viewModel);
        // validator = $("#editForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

        var contract_companiesDDl = $("#contract_SubContractor").kendoDropDownList({
            filter: "startswith",
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "ID",
            dataSource: viewModel.Compainies
          ,
            select:
                 function (e) {
                     var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                     console.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")");
                 },
            change: function () {
                console.log("event :: change");
            }
            //,autoBind: false
        });


        jQuery("#contractGrid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                       { title: "Contract Number", "width": "140px", "field": "ContractNumber", "encoded": true, "editor": null },
                        { title: "Title", "width": "180px", "field": "Title", "encoded": true, "editor": null },
                        { title: "Sub Contractor", "width": "190px", "field": "SubContractorName", "encoded": true, "editor": null },
                        { title: "Project", "width": "140px", "field": "ProjectName", "encoded": true, "editor": null },

                       {
                           "width": "180px", "command": [{ "name": "edit", "buttonType": "ImageAndText", "text": "Edit" },
                             { "name": "destroy", "buttonType": "ImageAndText", "text": "Delete" }]
                       }],
            pageable: { "buttonCount": 10 },
            sortable: true,
            selectable: "Single, Row",
            height: 350,
            filterable: true,
            excel: { "proxyURL": "/Contracts/Excel_Export_Save", "fileName": "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx", "filterable": true },
            pdf: { "proxyURL": "/Contracts/Pdf_Export_Save", "fileName": "Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf" },
            columnMenu: true,
            editable: {
                confirmation: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
                confirmDelete: "Delete",
                cancelDelete: "Cancel",

                window: {
                    title: "Edit", modal: true, draggable: true, resizable: false
                },
                create: true,
                update: true,
                destroy: true
            },
            // toolbar: ["create", "cancel"], // specify toolbar commands,
            dataSource: viewModel.dataSource
                ,
            navigatable: true,
            change: onContractGridChange
        });




    });


    function getContractDatasource() {
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: (function () { if (kendo.data.transports['webapi']) { return 'webapi'; } else { throw new Error('The kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js script is not included.'); } })(),
            transport: {
                read: { url: "/api/Contracts", data: listContractParams() },
                prefix: "",
                create: {
                    url: "/api/Contracts/PostContract",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/api/Contracts/PutContract/{0}",

                    type: "PUT"
                },
                destroy: { url: "/api/Contracts/{0}" },
                idField: "ID"
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            page: 1,
            total: 0,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverGrouping: true,
            serverAggregates: true,
            filter: [],
            schema: { "data": "Data", "total": "Total", "errors": "Errors", "model": { "id": "ID"} },

            change: function () {
                if (viewModel) {
                    viewModel.set("hasChanges", this.hasChanges());
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }


    function getContract_SubcontractorsDatasource() {
        return new kendo.data.DataSource(
          {
              type: 'odata',
              serverFiltering: true,
              transport: {
                  read: {
                      url: "api/Companies/GetCompanies",
                      dataType: 'json'

                  }
                  ,
                  parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                      var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                      delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter.
                      delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter.
                      return paramMap;
                  }
              }
                , schema: {
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                    },
                    total: function (data) {
                        return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                    },
                    model: { id: "ID", fields: { ID: { type: "number" }, Name: { type: "string" } } }
                }

                ,
              idField: "ID"
          }
        );
    }

    function onContractGridChange(arg) {

        grid = arg.sender;
        var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(this.select());
        viewModel.set("selected", currentDataItem);


    }

    function listContractParams() {
        if (projectid === null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { projectid: JSON.stringify(projectid) };
        }
    }




</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `selected.SubContractorID` when you open the form to edit a row? Is it a string or a number?

Comment: SubContractorID is a number